# Presto LDAP Authentication

Tags: ldap, presto, trino

I am running my Presto cluster locally and currently wanted to test LDAP authentication, i am following this [link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/ldap.html#ldap-server)

I have set up the configuration files as mentioned on the presto documents, when i run my server the output is displayed as :

```
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   PROPERTY                 DEFAULT     RUNTIME                                             DESCRIPTION
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.bind-dn             ----        ----                                                Bind distinguished name used by Presto. Example: CN=User Name,OU=CITY_OU,OU=STATE_OU,DC=domain,DC=domain_root
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.bind-password       [REDACTED]  [REDACTED]                                          Bind password used by Presto. Example: password1234
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.group-auth-pattern  ----        ----                                                Custom group authorization check query. Example: &(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=group)(user=username)
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.ignore-referrals    false       false                                               Referrals allow finding entries across multiple LDAP servers. Ignore them to only search within 1 LDAP server
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.cache-ttl           1.00h       1.00h
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.url                 ----        ldaps://ldapserver.home.com:389  URL of the LDAP server
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.user-base-dn        ----        ----                                                Base distinguished name of the user. Example: dc=example,dc=com
2020-07-24T17:06:25.077+0530    INFO    main    Bootstrap   ldap.user-bind-pattern   ----        ${USER}@mydomain.com                             Custom user bind pattern. Example: ${USER}@example.com
2020-07-24T17:06:25.199+0530    INFO    main    io.prestosql.server.security.PasswordAuthenticatorManager   -- Loaded password authenticator ldap --
2020-07-24T17:06:25.228+0530    INFO    main    io.prestosql.server.PrestoServer    ======== SERVER STARTED ========
```

I using Presto Cli to test the ldap below is the command:

```
 ./presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog bigquery --schema default
```

It doesn't ask for Password and i am able to connect to Presto cluster and was able to run query.
Why LDAP Authentication is not working any help regarding this ?

Answer (score 3):

The right documentation link for the version you are using is https://trino.io/docs/current/security/ldap.html#ldap-server.

To the point though, Presto does not use and does not allow authentication over HTTP. You need to configure HTTPS and use something like `--server https://localhost:8443` to connect to Presto.

Obviously, you need to make sure that users cannot reach the HTTP port. This can be done by network ingress rules, or by disabling the HTTP altogether. In the latter case, you need to configure Presto nodes to be able to authenticate between each other as well.

If you need help configuring Presto, you can always get it on the `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).